# Error while invoking AWS Lambda function through postman - 403 error

Tags: java, aws-lambda, invoke

I am building an Amazon lambda connector for WSO2 ESB and have my own signature generation class. For, calling Invoke method in REST API the data provided in postman are as follows:

```
{
    "secretAccessKey":"ZvLi*********",
    "accessKeyId":"********DBMEKSA",
    "region":"us-east-2",
    "blocking":"false",
    "functionName":"CustomFunction"
}
```

And the response message I got is:

```
{
    "message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."
}
```

The thing is, with the same signature generation class and with the similar type of data, all methods are working fine but this one. What might be wrong? The only difference in this method and the others is that they don't expect payload to be inserted like in this one. But anyway I am not giving any payload value since it is optional parameters. The optional and mandatory parameters are as follows

FunctionName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */

ClientContext: 'STRING_VALUE',

InvocationType: Event | RequestResponse | DryRun,

LogType: None | Tail,

Payload: new Buffer('...') || 'STRING_VALUE' /* Strings will be Base-64encoded on your behalf */,

Qualifier: 'STRING_VALUE'